# Найти и заменить слова в тегах в файле XML

Tags: xslt, xsl

Всем привет.

Помогите создать xsl можно 3 версии,
мне нужно в xml файле находить и менять значение в строке, например **Жесткий картон, 350 гр.** нужно изменить **Картон 350 гр** или **KREATO_350_B3** на **Креато 350 гр**.

Весь xml не стал выкладывать, но остальные параметры в нем должны остаться

**Вот сам xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zakazy>
    <params KodProverki=""
            obrabotki1Name="Жесткий картон, 350 гр."
            obrabotki1="KREATO_350_B3"
            
          />  
</zakazy>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Задавая вопрос XSLT, вам необходимо предоставить [минимальный воспроизводимый пример] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Исходный XML.
(2) Ваша логика и XSLT, который пытается ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат, основанный на образце XML в #1 выше.
(4) Процессор XSLT и его соответствие стандартам XSLT: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 или 4.0.
Все в рамках вопроса в виде текста, без картинок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно использует так называемый «Identity Transform» шаблон.

Версия №2 и №3 работают с последовательностями (sequences).

Алгоритм поиска и замены работает на основе местоположения в последовательностях.

**Исходный XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zakazy>
    <params KodProverki="" obrabotki1Name="Жесткий картон, 350 гр." obrabotki1="KREATO_350_B3"/>
</zakazy>
```

**XSLT 3.0, версия №1**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.='Жесткий картон, 350 гр.']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="'Картон 350 гр.'"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.='KREATO_350_B3']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="'Креато 350 гр.'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 3.0, версия №2**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.=('Жесткий картон, 350 гр.','KREATO_350_B3')]">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="index-of(('Жесткий картон, 350 гр.', 'KREATO_350_B3'), .)" />
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="subsequence(('Картон 350 гр.', 'Креато 350 гр.')
            , $pos, $pos)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 3.0, версия №3**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="sequence_find" select="'Жесткий картон, 350 гр.', 'KREATO_350_B3'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sequence_replace" select="'Картон 350 гр.', 'Креато 350 гр.'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.=$sequence_find]">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="index-of($sequence_find, .)"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="subsequence($sequence_replace, $pos, $pos)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<zakazy>
  <params KodProverki="" obrabotki1Name="Картон 350 гр." obrabotki1="Креато 350 гр."/>
</zakazy>
```

Comment: Спасибо вечером попробую. Дам знать результат.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. ВЫ БОЛЬШОЙ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛ!!! У меня к вам еще 1 вопрос, так как разновидностей бумаги много, можно как то подгружать их из внешнего файла? например: Есть файл xml в нем в каждой строке набраны бумаги и через тильду на что изменять: ART_150 **~** Art150_320x465. И так весь список. Возможно ли это сделать? Или может подскажите более изящное решение

Comment: Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает на вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить это как ответ.

Comment: По поводу вашего дополнительного вопроса. Пожалуйста, опубликуйте новый вопрос, используя **минимальный воспроизводимый пример**, как в комментарии.